# Generate Sin/Cos/Tan Values from Sympy by latex string

Tags: python, latex, sympy, trigonometry

I've  made a function to calculate latex expression by sympy:
here is the code

```
from sympy import latex, sympify
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
from sympy import latex, parse_expr

# ------->> Example LaTeX string
latex_string = r'\frac{30}{2}'

# ------->> Convert LaTeX string to a sympy expression
expr = parse_latex(latex_string)

# ------->> Evaluate the expression
result = expr.evalf()

# ------->> Print the result
print(result)
```

But when I send `\sin(30)` to this function it returns `-0.988031624092862` instead of `0.5`. I've searched a lot in stackoverflow and in Chat GPT also and got this to generate values of sin

```
import sympy as sp

# Calculate the sine of 30 degrees
result = sp.sin(sp.rad(30))

# Print the result
print(result)
```

But I want to send the input as `\sin(30)` (in latex) format. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sympy's trigonometric functions automatically evaluates the most important radians values. For example, `sin(pi / 4)` evaluates to `sqrt(2)/2`. Since you are providing angles in degree, evaluation should not happen. For example:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
s = r"\sin(30) + \cos\left(45\right)"
expr = parse_latex(s)
expr
# out: sin(30) + cos(45)
```

At this point you can post-process `expr` to convert the arguments of trigonometric functions from degrees to radians:

```py
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import TrigonometricFunction

# finds all trigonometric functions
trigs = expr.find(TrigonometricFunction)

# loop over each match, replace it with a new trig function with angle in radians
for t in trigs:
    expr = expr.replace(t, t.func(t.args[0] * pi / 180))
expr
# out: 1/2 + sqrt(2)/2
```

EDIT: You might want to apply the substitution only if the argument of the trigonometric function is a number. If that's the case:

```py
s = r"\sin(30) + \cos\left(45\right) + \cos(x)"
expr = parse_latex(s)
for t in trigs:
    if t.args[0].is_Number:
        expr = expr.replace(t, t.func(t.args[0] * pi / 180))
expr
# out: cos(x) + 1/2 + sqrt(2)/2
```

Final EDIT: to take into account inverse trigonometric functions:

```py
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import InverseTrigonometricFunction

s = r"\arcsin(0) + \arccos(1/2)"
expr = parse_latex(s)

inverse_trigs = expr.find(InverseTrigonometricFunction)

# loop over each match, replace it with a new inverse trig function
for t in inverse_trigs:
    expr = expr.replace(t, t * 180 / pi)
expr
# out: 180*asin(0)/pi + 180*acos(1/2)/pi
```

Comment: @Koushik If this answers your question then you should accept the answer by clicking on the gray check next to the solution.

Comment: But it is not working for `\arcsin(0.5)` !

Comment: updated answer to take into account inverse trigonometric functions. Next time it would be best if you would better formulate your question.